# How do I dynamically attach an 'li' element to its parent 'ul' in pug

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am new to pug and am trying to figure out how to append an `li` element to its parent `ul` in my node.js project.

I have an unordered list `ul#messages` that I'll populate later in my code to give a list of messages. However, I have a strong feeling the tags around `li` the oughtn't be there but I still can't figure it out yet. I've done an decent research on here, google and the pug website https://pugjs.org/ but to no avail. Below is the code I want converted to pug:
`$('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));`

I'd appreciate it a lot if I could be assited

Answer (score 0):

Pug does this through two space indentation.

This:

```
ul#messages
  li= msg
```

Will produce this HTML:

```
<ul id='messages'>
  <li>This is the message</li>
</ul>
```

You can also use the `each` operator to easily generate a series of `li` elements.